# Independent sectioning commands for minipage

Tags: sectioning, minipage

My document has several `minipage`-environments that need an inner sectioning with numeration independent of the "normal" sectioning of the document. Until now I have used a work-around and simply hard-coded the headers as paragraphs and applied the numbering and formatting by hand, e.g.

```
\begin{minipage}
  \begin{center}Title\end{center}

  \textbf{1 First section}

  Some Text

  \textit{1.1 First subsection}

  Some more Text

  \textit{1.2 Second subsection}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{enumerate}

  \textbf{2 Second section}

  Even more Text
\end{minipage}
```

However, this caused some blemishes like too narrow vertical spacing between headers and normal paragraphs in comparison to the vertical space between a "header" followed immediately by a list-environment. Moreover, I would like to have no indention of the first paragraph after a section. To make it short: I would like to have all this nice spacing correction "magic" that is applied by proper sectioning commands.

I would like to define three special minipage (mp) sectioning macros:

- `\mptitle`: First command in minipage to print a centered title
- `\mpsection`: 1st-level sectioning
- `\mpsubsection`: 2nd-level sectioning

with the following properties

- Numbering restarts for each minipage (i.e. similar to footnotes inside minipages)
- Entry in TOC not required and not wanted
- Proper vertical spacing before and after with all these nice spacing corrections, if two sectioning commands immediately follows each other, no indention of following paragraph, corrections for lists, etc.
- Working cross-reference (i.e. using `\label`) is nice to have, but not yet required

I had a look into source2e.pdf, chap. 61 and tried to figure out what `\@startsection`, `\@sect` and friends do and if I possible could re-use them, but I failed. Firstly, I was lost to really understand how these commands work. Secondly, I got the impression that the LEVEL parameter will always interfere with the normal sectioning (I read that is must be unique) and it seems that `\@startsection`, `\@sect` always manipulate the TOC.

I would really glad if somebody could help me to define `\mptitle`, `\mpsection` and `\mpsubsection` analogous to what the normal sectioning commands do but omit all the unnecessary code that is required for TOC.

Comment: I am not sure about what kind of "magic space" you need... otherwise that could be done with a couple of counters and specific macros to typeset the section/subsection thingy.

Comment: @nagmat84 AFAICT, `\@startsection` doesn't touch the TOC if called with a star following (since this is what `\section*` and friends do). When `\@ifstar` is tested at the end of `\@startsection`'s definition, if the result is true, `\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}` is left in the input stream, which should not alter the TOC (note that it's `\@ssect` in this case, not `\@sect` as used for numbered sections). To suppress indentation after a heading made with `\@startsection`, pass it a negative `#4` (*beforeskip*).

Comment: @frougon The starred version of \@startsection does not help here, because it does not only skip a TOC entry, but does not number the section at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code [you posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498774/73317), this implements your items 1, 2 and 3 (item 2, i.e, removing penalty insertions, doesn't seem very important, though).

You may want to consider defining your own environment that wraps `minipage` and resets the high-level counter (the code given below does that for `minipage`, as per your request):

```latex
\AtBeginEnvironment{yourminipagewrapper}{%
  \setcounter{mpsection}{0}%
}
```

This could be helpful if further customizations are needed in the future. Note that the low-level counter `mpsubsection` doesn't need to be manually reset, since it is subordinate to the higher-level counter `mpsection` according to your definition:

```latex
\newcounter{mpsubsection}[mpsection]
```

Also, your `minipage`-wrapping environment could accept an additional argument used when defining `\@currentlabel`, otherwise when you see a reference text like « 1.2 », you know it is a section 1.2, but don't know which `minipage` it belongs to (`hyperref` knows, though). But this very much depends on how you are going to use all this, so I can only offer simple suggestions like this.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

% #1 Name
% #2 Indent
% #3 Beforeskip
% #4 Afterskip
% #5 Style
% #6 Heading
\newcommand*{\@mpstartsection}[6]{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{cont@#1}% this counter is never reset, used for hyperref
  \stepcounter{#1}% counter used for display purposes
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{% define how refs look
    \csname p@#1\endcsname \csname the#1\endcsname
  }%
  \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \begingroup
    #5{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2\relax\@svsec}#6\@@par}%
  \endgroup
  \par
  \vskip #4\relax
  % \@afterheading deals with penalities related to page breaking that aren't
  % needed inside a minipage, but it also honors the \if@afterindent switch,
  % therefore leave it here.
  \@afterheading
  \ignorespaces
}

\newcounter{mpsection}
\newcounter{mpsubsection}[mpsection]

\newcounter{cont@mpsection}
\newcounter{cont@mpsubsection}

\renewcommand\thempsection{\@arabic\c@mpsection}
\renewcommand\thempsubsection{\thempsection.\@arabic\c@mpsubsection}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{%
  \setcounter{mpsection}{0}%
}

\newcommand\mpsection{\@mpstartsection{mpsection}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\mpsubsection{\@mpstartsection{mpsubsection}{\z@}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}

\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \mpsection{Foo bar section}
  \label{sec-foobar}%

  \lipsum[1]. See~\ref{sec-subbleh}.

  \mpsection{The baz and the quux}
  \label{sec-baz-quux}%

  \lipsum[2]. See~\ref{sec-foobar} and~\ref{sec-other-subbleh}.
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
  \mpsection{Bleh}
  \label{sec-bleh}%

  \lipsum[1][2-3]. See~\ref{sec-baz-quux}.

  \mpsubsection{Sub-bleh}
  \label{sec-subbleh}%

  \lipsum[2][4-5]. See~\ref{sec-subouch}.

  \mpsubsection{Other sub-bleh}
  \label{sec-other-subbleh}%

  Bla bla \lipsum[12].

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
  \mpsection{Ouch!}
  \label{sec-ouch}%

  \lipsum[1][6-7]

  \mpsubsection{Sub-ouch!}
  \label{sec-subouch}%

  \lipsum[2][8]. See~\ref{sec-ouch} and~\ref{sec-baz-quux}.

  \mpsection{Pouet}
  \label{sec-pouet}%

  \lipsum[3][1-2].

  \mpsubsection{Sub-pouet}

  \lipsum[3][4-5]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

On page 1:

[image: On page 1]

---

On page 2:

[image: On page 2]

Comment: It's excellent the way it is. It is OK, that the printable versions of references to minipage sections are ambiguous. Every minipage is inside a floating figure environment. If I refer to a section inside a minipage, I only do so in combination with a reference to the figure environment. I.e. I always write something like "see `\ref{sec:mp-section}` in `\ref{fig:minipage}`".

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer** -- Improvements welcomed

That is what I have already achieved. The solution is based on what the original `\@startsection` and `\@sect` and `\@xsect`-macros do. I omitted some if-then-else branches that are not required for minipages, throw out the TOC-code and combined the remaining code into one macro.

```
\makeatletter

% #1 Name
% #2 Indent
% #3 Beforeskip
% #4 Afterskip
% #5 Style
% #6 Heading
\def\@mpstartsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \begingroup
    #5{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2\relax\@svsec}\interlinepenalty \@M #6\@@par}
  \endgroup
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip #4\relax
  \@afterheading
  \ignorespaces
}

\newcounter{mpsection}
\newcounter{mpsubsection}[mpsection]

\renewcommand\thempsection{\@arabic\c@mpsection}
\renewcommand\thempsubsection{\thempsection.\@arabic\c@mpsubsection}

\newcommand\mpsection{\@mpstartsection{mpsection}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\mpsubsection{\@mpstartsection{mpsubsection}{\z@}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}

\makeatother
```

**Required improvements**

1. Reset the `mpsection`-counter for each minipage.
2. The code above can probably simplified even more and some penalties are superfluous, because page breaks within minipages are impossible.
3. If 1. was implemented, I would receive a lot of "duplicate destination" errors together with hyperef and cross-references, because there is a section *n* in each minipage. Somehow the `\mptitle` command (not implemented yet) need to implement an "invisible" counter that makes the sections unique.